# Sitecore XP 10.3.1, Sitecore Headless Services Server XP 21.0.587

Tags: solution-architecture

I have created article detail page. On that page I have dropped a placeholder where I am dropping nextArticle Component. What will be the best approach to get only one article in the nextArticle. We can use the ordering that is done CMS.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a datasource on your rendering which will point to a nextArticle item.

Other option is to point to an next article list folder and to take first article but I believe the first option is better.

Comment: I want to automate it. I want next article to be selected on basis of datefield rather than CMS author having to update it manually or adding it manually every time new article is added.

Comment: Thanks Vlad Iobagiu. I used another approach. I wrote a custom Layout resolver, and used solr search to get items of same template except the current item. then used linq to filter through it to find only one relevant item. Had to build computed field index for date and Image though.

Answer (score 0):

As i understand your question and comment, You are working in headless and you want that nextArticle to be automatically selected based on the date

Why don't you write your custom resolver, You can use context item resolver and write a logic which will find the next best item to be displayed in that component and return that from your custom resolver

You own the business logic and you can use date filed to identify which item you want to show in that component

Let me know your thoughts or if i am understanding it correctly.

Comment: Thanks. This  is exactly what I did. This also means that I had to create custom field indexing for datefield and Imagefield. I used solr search to find the article that meet nextarticle requirement.

Comment: Oh perfect !!! Enjoy